# Como crear filas e ingresar datos Boostrap

Tags: javascript

la verdad estoy bastante perdida con esto de las tablas y JavaScript, lo que deseo saber es como ingresar o mejor dicho crear filas a una tabla creada con Boostrap, y a la vez ingresarle ciertos datos. La estructura de las filas a crear seria esta;

`<tr>
  <th scope="row">dato</th>
  <td>dato</td>
  <td>dato</td>
  <td>dato</td>
</tr>`

dejo el codigo de la tabla estandar de boostrap a la cual requiero hacerle el ingreso de filas y a la vez datos.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table">
          <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">cal 1</th>
              <th scope="col">cal 2</th>
              <th scope="col">cal 3</th>
              <th scope="col">cal 4</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
             <!-- aqui ingresar las filas --> 
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: De donde vas a sacar los datos que quieres ingresar?

Comment: son cálculos, el valor inicial lo tomare del mismo DOM y lo procesare con JavaScript, son varios resultado, y es lo que deseo ingresar a la tabla.

Answer (score 1):

Si mal no entendí vos querés desde javascript ingresar filas a la tabla que tenes con bootstrap no?.

En caso de que te haya entendido bien, tenes varias formas de hacerlo. Te paso dos que se me ocurren en este momento:

1) Armar el html en una variable e insertarlo.

```
var html = '<tr>';
html += '<th scope="row">dato</th>';
html += '<td>dato1</td>';
html += '<td>dato2</td>';
html += '<td>dato3</td>';
html += '</tr>';

$('table tbody').html(html);
```

Recorda que tambien podes agregar un id a la tabla (ej: id="myTable") y despues en javascript buscarla asi: $('#myTable tbody')

2) Armar fila por fila e insertarlas con la funcion "append" de jquery.

```
var html = '<tr>';
html += '<th scope="row">dato</th>';
html += '<td>dato1</td>';
html += '<td>dato2</td>';
html += '<td>dato3</td>';
html += '</tr>';

$('table tbody').append(html);
```

Recorda que para esto tenes que descargar jquery. Lo podes hacer desde la pagina oficial.

Espero que te sea de utilidad lo que te dije. Saludos

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, logre solucionar de una manera mucho mas corta.. gracias.

Answer (score 1):

he logrado resolver de la siguiente manera.

`var dato1 = 1;
var dato2 = 2;
var dato3 = 3;

var row="<tr><td>"+ dato1 +"</td><td>"+dato2 +"</td><td>"+ dato3;
var ins = document.createElement("TR");
ins.innerHTML = row;
document.getElementById("table").appendChild(ins);`

gracias a todos por la ayuda.